# Stratification of a family of a rational curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to Y$ be a flat family of rational curves over complex numbers.Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Then one can stratify $Y$ in to locally closed subsets
$Y_i:= \{y \in Y: h^0(X_y, E_y) \ge i\}$. Assume that $Y_i \ne \varnothing$ and $Y_1 \setminus Y_2 \ne \varnothing$.

Question: Is it possible that $Y_i=Y_{i-1}$ ?

Comment: Almost any pathology you can imagine does happen, even for the vector bundles arising as normal bundles of rational curves in a Fano manifold.  One article about this is by Izzet Coskun and Eric Riedl: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06149

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.